# Divide the image into 4x4 blocks and save each coordinate in variable

Tags: python, image, python-2.7, opencv, image-processing

I have an grayscale Image of 128x128 that I want to divide into 4x4 pixel non-overlapping blocks and I want to save coordinate of each pixel as variable like this-

```
pixel1=x,y
pixel2=x,y
pixel3=x,y
pixel4=x,y..and so on to
......
......
......
pixel16384=x,y
```

I know I can do it manually by defining variables, but I can use any `for` loop for making it faster?
After that, I'll find mean of each block by-

```
Average_of_block1=pixel1.mean(),pixel2.mean(),pixel3.mean(),pixel4.mean()....pixel16.mean()
```

Any help?Suggestions?

Comment: Pretty sure `cv2` images are numpy arrays. If so you could use [sklearn's extract_patches_2d](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.image.extract_patches_2d.html) to get the patches.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the value of the pixel you could use PIL and
you could use a for loop and append a tuple of the x and y coordinate like this:

```
from PIL import Image
pixels = []
i = Image.open("image.jpg")
p = i.load()
for x in range(128):
    for y in range(128):
        pixels.append(p[x,y]) #gets the RGB value
```

this would work for the whole image for those blocks you could just add an extra loop

```
from PIL import Image
pixels = []
i = Image.open("image.jpg")
p = i.load()
for b in range(4):
    block = []
    for x in range(32):
        for y in range(32):
            block.append(p[x,y])
    #do something with pixels from block
```

**edit:**
If you want to use a grayscale image you should do this:

```
from PIL import Image
pixels = []
i = Image.open("image.jpg").convert("LA") 
p = i.load()
for b in range(4):
    block = []
    for x in range(32):
        for y in range(32):
            block.append(p[x,y][0])
    #do something with the pixels from the block
```

the first int in the tuple is the grayscale 0 (black) to 255 (white) the second int is the alpha but my guess would be that you don't use alpha in a grayscale image

Comment: I'm sorry that I forgot to mention that image is grayscale.Now I had updated the question.Now how can I get the value of 1 grayscale pixel?